# Wordpress get_permalink() PHP Link not working for external links in posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Using wordpress and editing some PHP code in my child theme and have run into an issue with a sidebar widget for popular posts.

Each blog post in wordpress that is popular accurately shows up in the popular posts sidebar, and clicking the story title it will go to the single story page *on my blog*.

The correct code in this widget to link to my own blog posts in widgets.php is:

```
    if ( $popular_posts->have_posts() ) {
        $result .= '<div class="post-popular"><ul class="list">';
        while ( $popular_posts->have_posts() ) {
            $popular_posts->the_post();
            $comments_text = sprintf( _n( '%1$s comment', '%1$s comments', get_comments_number(), APP_TD ), get_comments_number() );
            $result .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a> - ' . $comments_text . '</li>';
        }
        $result .= '</ul></div>';
    }
```

Since this is a sidebar widget of popular articles, I would like the sidebar clicks to go directly to the **external site** for each article, and not my blog posts.

Within each blog post is a direct **external** link to the actual article for each.
This is tagged for each post as the following code **article_out_url**

I tried the following code edit for get_permalink() to make it get_permalink($url) to go to each external such such as:

```
$url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'article_out_url', true );
$result .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($url) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a> - ' . $comments_text . '</li>';
```

Such as the following:

```
    if ( $popular_posts->have_posts() ) {
        $result .= '<div class="post-popular"><ul class="list">';
        while ( $popular_posts->have_posts() ) {
            $url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'article_out_url', true );
            $popular_posts->the_post();
            $comments_text = sprintf( _n( '%1$s comment', '%1$s comments', get_comments_number(), APP_TD ), get_comments_number() );
            $result .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($url) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a> - ' . $comments_text . '</li>';
        }
        $result .= '</ul></div>';
    }
```

However, this didn't work. Instead of going to the external link, clicking on the link simply went to my root domain only. Not even the individual post on the topic.

I'm stumped. Any ideas with how I can get each article link to go to the the article_out_url URL for each post? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

read http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink

inside loop it's the current post.
outside loop you need a post id.

but it's a post on your blog.

i think the solution is easier than you imagine. grab the url, and stick it in the href. you may want to trim it. (post meta is a bit junk in junk out.)

Comment: Rob, thank you for your comment. The issue is that I can't put a direct URL in the href since it's dynamic based on the post. 

With the inside/outside loop consideration, I thought I was doing it right including 

    $url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'article_out_url', true );

in the PHP file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

get_permalink() only works for WordPress Posts and Pages, not external links.